# Не работает SetResolution на Bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, графика, dpi

Немного не понимаю, почему не работает данный код:

```
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    fs.CopyTo(ms);
                }
                using (var bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms))
                {

                    bmp.SetResolution(300, 300);
                    bmp.Save(@"E:\Projects\My Projects\ChangeDPI\test.png");
                }
            }
```

Т.е на выходе DPI у картинки остается без изменений.

Если из bmp создать новый Bitmap, то все успешно сохраняется.

Это какая-то особенной библиотеки или я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: Вроде бы баг: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19184265/276994

Comment: @VladD, а в более независимой от ОС манере можно работать с картинками не прибегая к другим либам? Например, через классы WPF? Вроде бы в этом фреймворке хотели уйти от GDI+.Если баги ОС неохотно правят, то фреймворк свой должны более хорошо поддерживать.

Comment: Ну, WPF вроде тоже системно-зависимый, хотя и меньше. Но я не пробовал менять разрешение через WPF, надо попробовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй заменить

```
bmp.SetResolution(300, 300);
```

на

```
bmp = new Bitmap(bmp, new Size(300, 300));
```

скорее всего получится и не прибегая к сторонним либам. Отпишись решило ли проблему.

Comment: Ну это похоже на решение которое я нашел в виде создания нового bmp на основе bmp из файла. Похоже, что других красивых решений нет.